# Is there a HTML api which allows me show a div container on "#route"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document

Many single page websites provide a navigation which moves the current snippet of a document to another one. An example is the site of backbonejs: http://backbonejs.org/
When you click left on a menu point you will see this one in the document.
Another example is the navigation bar of easel.io: https://www.easel.io

Is there a HTML5 API which does this for me or do I have to use js with click handlers?

Comment: Please don't use [signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any API, that's pure HTML. You have to use anchor tag like this

```
<a href="#Events-on">on</a>
```

and then you'll have a target element with the id pointed by `href`

```
<p id="Events-on">...</p>
```